# How To Initialize Tile Source Just Once In IBAction Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference, initialization, mapbox

In my project, I have multiple tile sources that I add to a map. I have a button for each tile source. I want the button to addTileSource when pressed the first time, then the next time removeTileSource and continue to alternate this way. My problem is that it won't removeTileSource because it's removing a different myTileSource that is created each time I press the button since I initialize the object before the if statement. How can I resolve this? I've tried initializing the tile source in viewDidLoad and in the if-statement but it errors 'use of undeclared identifier' in the other locations I call on it. Please review my code and make suggestions as to how I can achieve my intended goal. Thanks for your time.

```
- (IBAction)LayerButton:(id)sender 
{
    RMMBTilesSource *myTileSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MapName" ofType:@"mbtiles"]]];
    FirstViewController *FVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    self.phase3BIsChecked = !self.phase3BIsChecked;

    if((self.phase3BIsChecked)) {
        [[FVC mapView] addTileSource:myTileSource];
        self.phase3BButtonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        self.phase3BButtonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [[FVC mapView] removeTileSource:myTileSource];
    }

    NSLog(@"Map Index = %@", [[[FVC mapView] tileSources]  description]);
    if ([[[FVC mapView] tileSources] containsObject:myTileSource]) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

When I press the button the first time, the map loads and I get "YES". When I press it the second time, the map doesn't turn off and I get "NO". This pretty much sums up my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface definition for your view controller, add this variable definition:

```
RMMBTilesSource *myTileSource;
```

In your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, add this:

```
myTileSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MapName" ofType:@"mbtiles"]]];
```

Your `LayerButton` action then can become this:

```
- (IBAction)LayerButton:(id)sender {
    FirstViewController *FVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    self.phase3BIsChecked = !self.phase3BIsChecked;

    if((self.phase3BIsChecked)) {
        [[FVC mapView] addTileSource:myTileSource];
        self.phase3BButtonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        self.phase3BButtonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [[FVC mapView] removeTileSource:myTileSource];
    }

    NSLog(@"Map Index = %@", [[[FVC mapView] tileSources]  description]);
    if ([[[FVC mapView] tileSources] containsObject:myTileSource]) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you.